# How to import VMT (valve materials) to blender materials?

Tags: materials

i need to import or reproduce **VMT** to **blender materials**.
i know how to deals with texture but i dont know, for exemple, **$bumpmap**
does there is an actual documentation how to reproduce valve materials into blender?

Answer (score 0):

From what I gathered, PhongWarp seems to be either Specular or Metallic, Phong is how strong the PhongWarp is. PhongExponent seems to be roughness, with the non-texture variant being how strong/bright it is. BumpMap is just a normal texture.

Answer (score 0):

VMT files can't be directly imported into Blender. What you can do is use VTFEdit to see where to put each file in the material section. As to your question on bumpmap, that is the input for a normal map.

Answer (score 0):

VMT files show how the material works. You can open it in VTFEdit to see what textures go where, but it can't be directly imported into Blender.

Answer (score 0):

there would be notoriety found for a coder to automate this,
But unfortunately the only way to import .vmt functions now is manual.
(By using nodes)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).